# create registration form and roles asp mvc identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I'm very confused about creating registration form. I am building a shopping cart website and i want users to register on my website. for this i have user table in my DB, also an admin table. when i create new project using built-in mvc template it provide controller (which are really great) uses its own DB.

1) i want to store the registered user information in my DB and also login them not with the default DB Context
2) i have 2 tables (Users, Admin) now how can i use role manager on both tables ? should i put Admin's table ID in auto created tables (aspnetroles, aspnetcalims, aspnetuserroles) or should i make only 1 table of name USERS and manage roles ?

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default User table for all users since you have roles to differentiate them. Creating another table for users in an admin role will just add nearly identical table to maintain.

If you want to use your own DB context, you can derive it from `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` or `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>` instead of `DbContext` and then use it for identity as well.

You can further customize ASP.NET Identity schema by extending it's entity classes such as IdentityUser.

```
class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string MyColumn { get; set; }
}
```

For more control, you can extend `IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim>` to specify types for keys other than string(uniqueidentifier), custom entities for roles, etc.

You can map default identity entities to a custom table as with any other EF entities using Fluent API by overriding `OnModelCreating` of your DB context and using `DbModelBuilder`.

e.g.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("MyUsers");
```

ASP.NET Identity is very customizable. You should not have any problems extending it, if you are familiar with Entity Framework.

Some basic examples:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

Comment: wow.. thank you so much. it really helped me to understand :)